# Extract GO-IDs and Go names of topGO data object

Tags: r, annotations, ontology

I have successfully created a topGO data object in R. Now I want to extract the GO-ID, GO term and included genes in a matrix. The *ann.genes* variable is a list of character vectors, i.e

```
$`GO:0005524`
[1] "1432" "1956" "207"  "2534" "3320" "6714"
```

How can I get/extract the 'GO:00005524' ID name and find the corresponding GO term somewhere in the topGO object or load it from the topGO database?
names(ann.genes) is applicable here. Now how to get the GO term?

Thank you very much.